# Принцип локализации на Android

Tags: android, locale

Как правильно локализовать приложение на андроид, чтобы можно было в настройках например кликнуть на `radiobutton` или `checkbox` и устанавливался выбранный язык. Я себе это как представляю, сделать, либо замещать весь текст в активити текстом другого языка при выборе, либо создать новые активити с другими языками и уже при выборе другого языка менять просто активити, либо еще какие-то есть мне не известные способы. Может кто-то сможет посоветовать рабочий способ.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если необходимо менять язык на лету, делайте следующее.

1) Создаете ресурсы в string.xml

```
<resources>
 <string name="app_name">Change Language</string>
 <string name="hello">Hello</string>
 <string name="welcome">Welcome,</string>
</resources>
```

потом ресурсы для второго языка, например Французский values-fr/string.xml

```
<resources>
 <string name="app_name">Changer de langue</string>
 <string name="hello">Bonjour</string>
 <string name="welcome">Bienvenue,</string>
</resources>
```

2) Создаете класс помощник

```
package devdeeds.com.changelanguage;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Build;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

import java.util.Locale;

public class LocaleHelper {

private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
    String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    return setLocale(context, lang);
}

public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
    String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
    return setLocale(context, lang);
}

public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
    return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
}

public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
    persist(context, language);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return updateResources(context, language);
    }

    return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
}

private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
}

private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

    editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
    editor.apply();
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.setLocale(locale);

    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    Resources resources = context.getResources();

    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;

    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

    return context;
 }
}
```

3) Меняете язык

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String mLanguageCode = "fr";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //меняем Английский на Французский по клику на кнопку
    findViewById(R.id.btnChangeLangView).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Change Application level locale
            LocaleHelper.setLocale(MainActivity.this, mLanguageCode);

            //Пересоздаем Активити с новым языком.
            recreate();
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Если надо, можете запомнить выбранный язык в SharedPreference и в onCreate() сетить методом LocaleHelper.setLocale(MainActivity.this, mLanguageCode).

[первоисточник](http://devdeeds.com/android-change-language-at-runtime/)