# Проблема с локализацией приложения Android

Tags: android, android-studio, checkbox, locale

Несколько дней назад мне здесь помогли с локализацией приложения на Андроид. Расписано было все полностью и по пунктам как и что сделать что бы приложение получило несколько языков. Я все сделал как было написано, но приложение не смогло изменить язык на лету. То есть я сделал 3 чекбокса с повешенным на них языком, и при выборе определенного чекбокса у меня должен меняться язык. Но как все происходит у меня: я выбираю язык нажав на чекбокс и как результат прога зависает полностью. Я пробовал на 5 и 7 андроиде, на телефонах с разной озу, но результат один и тот же. Может проблема в том что я использую чекбоксы, может в том что я неправильно перерисовываю активити, может еще в чем то я ошибся. Буду благодарен за любую помощь и советы. Вот ссылка на вопрос по локализации: [Принцип локализации на Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821538/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android).
Вот код checkbox:

```
RadioGroup radGrp = findViewById(R.id.radios);
            radGrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() //слушатель для выбора цвета светодиода
            {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int id) {
                    byte k;
                    String color = null;
                    switch (id) {

                        case R.id.red:
                            LocaleHelper.setLocale(MainActivity.this, mLanguageCode1);

                            //Пересоздаем Активити с новым языком.
                            recreate();
                            break;
                        case R.id.green:
                            LocaleHelper.setLocale(MainActivity.this, mLanguageCode2);

                            //Пересоздаем Активити с новым языком.
                            recreate();;
                            break;
                        case R.id.blue:
                            LocaleHelper.setLocale(MainActivity.this, mLanguageCode3);

                            //Пересоздаем Активити с новым языком.
                            recreate();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

При запуске проекта когда он строится вначале у меня выводит ошибку:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.
```

Вот ошибка которая у меня выводится:

```
05-04 08:36:03.507 738-738/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-04 08:36:03.507 738-738/? I/art: VMHOOK: rlim_cur : 0 pid:738
05-04 08:36:03.597 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization I/art: override thread count:-j4
05-04 08:36:03.647 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.andrew.localization-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.andrew.localization-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
05-04 08:36:03.807 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization I/art: override thread count:-j4
05-04 08:36:03.857 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.andrew.localization-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.andrew.localization-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
05-04 08:36:03.857 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization I/art: override thread count:-j4
05-04 08:36:03.907 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.andrew.localization-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.andrew.localization-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
05-04 08:36:03.907 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization I/art: override thread count:-j4
05-04 08:36:03.957 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.andrew.localization-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.andrew.localization-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
05-04 08:36:03.967 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization I/art: override thread count:-j4
05-04 08:36:04.007 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.andrew.localization-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.andrew.localization-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
05-04 08:36:04.017 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization I/art: override thread count:-j4
05-04 08:36:04.067 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.andrew.localization-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.andrew.localization-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
05-04 08:36:04.077 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization I/art: override thread count:-j4
05-04 08:36:04.127 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.andrew.localization-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.andrew.localization-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
05-04 08:36:04.127 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization I/art: override thread count:-j4
05-04 08:36:04.187 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.andrew.localization-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.andrew.localization-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
05-04 08:36:04.187 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization I/art: override thread count:-j4
05-04 08:36:04.237 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.andrew.localization-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.andrew.localization-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
05-04 08:36:04.237 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization I/art: override thread count:-j4
05-04 08:36:04.287 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.andrew.localization-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.andrew.localization-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
05-04 08:36:04.287 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization I/art: override thread count:-j4
05-04 08:36:04.337 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm64 --instruction-set-features=smp,a53 --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m -j4 --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.andrew.localization-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm64/data@app@com.example.andrew.localization-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex -j4) because non-0 exit status
05-04 08:36:04.337 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.andrew.localization-2/lib/arm64
05-04 08:36:04.347 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
05-04 08:36:04.497 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
05-04 08:36:04.857 738-803/com.example.andrew.localization I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 8249e7b, Iacb76f3f7d
                                                                     Build Date                       : 03/22/16
                                                                     OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.05
                                                                     Local Branch                     : 
                                                                     Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BR.1.2.6_RB1.06.00.01.179.016
                                                                     Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                     Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
05-04 08:36:04.927 738-738/com.example.andrew.localization W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
05-04 08:36:21.757 738-749/com.example.andrew.localization I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 24590(1831KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 11% free, 14MB/16MB, paused 9.026ms total 83.985ms
```

Если будут вопросы в коментах отвечу.

Comment: Ссылка на тот вопрос должна быть в этом. И код с чекбоксами в вопрос добавьте. Скорее всего у вас там в цикл бесконечный всё валится из-за дёрганья слушателей чекбоксов.

Comment: код, с которым проблемы и стректрейс ошибки при падении приложения в вопрос необходимо добавить, чтобы получить какой то полезный ответ.

Comment: Так что есть идеи в чем у меня проблема???