# Как изменить локаль во всем приложении android без перезагрузки?

Tags: android, locale

Как во всем приложении изменить язык на другой, имеется в виду не именно на одной активити а во всем приложении, например есть три активити и нужно что-бы везде поменялся язык, без падений приложения. Я пробовал описанный способ в моем предыдущем вопросе [Принцип локализации на Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821538/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android) но у меня меняется язык только на одном экране и при попытке перехода дальше у меня слетает приложение. Пробовал исправить ошибку которая была во время падения приложения, но показывает на переменную которая нормально работает без применения локализации а как только ввожу локали то сразу тупит почему-то.

Comment: Без перезагрузки активити сделать нельзя средствами системы. Нельзя `просто` сделать. Вам надо, например, подменять `Resources` системы или, хотя бы, отлавливать изменение конфигурации при возврате на активити и пересоздавать её заново. Кажется, там метод `onRecreate()` нужен

Comment: нет, за перезагрузку активити я не против, она пересоздается на лету, мне нужно что-бы приложение само не перезагружалось, то есть выбрали язык, и он применился на лету во всех активити а не только на одной

Comment: Это невозможно в силу несуществования других активити. Т.е. одновременно всего одна живая активити может быть и всеми остальными управлять нельзя. Вам надо просто при входе/возврате к к-л активити проверять что её локаль соответствует локализации в настройках. И пересоздавать если нет

Comment: то есть по факту можно на одной активити менять язык, и потом просто перекидывать значение локализации в другие активити при их активации, только нужно как-то запоминать язык и все??

Comment: Да, всё верно. Сохраните язык в виде строки в префах и во всех активити проверяйте, что язык ресурсов активити совпадает с сохраненным в префах

Comment: вот сразу возникло несколько тупых вопросов, если я правильно понял то "префы" это preferencies но я ни разу не видел и не работал с таким видом ресурсов, второй вопрос если мы сохраняем наш язык в префах то как потом его проверить? обращаться к определенной строке или как?

Comment: Да, префы - `SharedPreferences`, в данном случае полученные через `PreferencesManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`. Там хранятся пары ключ-значение. Запишите по к-л ключу строку с кодом языка (ru, en, fr) и, получая в активити локаль из ресурсов в виде строки вычлените из неё код языка и сравните с тем, что в префах.

Comment: ок, спасибо за помощь буду разбираться))