# Не работает программная локализация приложения Android

Tags: android, locale, android-resources

У меня в приложении нужно менять язык, пользователь начинает свою работу с приложением с экрана входа и я решил что нужно менять язык всего приложения на этом этапе, то есть пользователь должен выбрать один язык который будет использоваться во всем остальном приложении. Для решения поставленной задачи я использовал советы и информацию из этого вопроса [Принцип локализации на Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821538/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android). [image: Так выглядит Alert Dialog для изменения локали]

Для утверждения выбора пользователя я использовал такой код:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.language) {
        list = new String[] {"English","Русский","Українська"};
        AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
        mBuilder.setTitle("Выберите язык");
        mBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_globe_solid);
        mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(list, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                if(i == 0)
                {
                    //Change Application level locale
                    LocaleHelper.setLocale(LoginActivity.this, mLanguageCode_en);
                    //Пересоздаем Активити с новым языком.
                    recreate();
                }
                if(i == 1)
                {
                    //Change Application level locale
                    LocaleHelper.setLocale(LoginActivity.this, mLanguageCode_rus);
                    //Пересоздаем Активити с новым языком.
                    recreate();
                }
                if(i == 2)
                {
                    //Change Application level locale
                    LocaleHelper.setLocale(LoginActivity.this, mLanguageCode_ua);
                    //Пересоздаем Активити с новым языком.
                    recreate();
                }
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });

        mBuilder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });

        AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
        mDialog.show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

и у меня после выбора почему-то ничего не происходит, вроде все должно работать мне так кажется, и можно ли использовать данный способ для изменения языка во всем приложении. Буду благодарен за помощь и полезные советы.

Метод setLocale():

```
public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResources(context, language);
        }

        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
    }
```

Переменные mLanguageCode:

```
 private String mLanguageCode_rus = "ru";
    private String mLanguageCode_en = "en";
    private String mLanguageCode_ua = "ua";
```

Comment: Для таких сравнений есть оператор ``switch(i)``. А ``recreate()`` можно вынести за скобки, а то у вас три раза повторяется.

Comment: Покажите метод ``setLocale()`` и переменные ``mLanguageCode_en`` и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте по другому:

```
public static Context setLocale(Context context, String locale) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
        configuration.setLocale(locale);
    else
        configuration.locale=locale;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        getApplicationContext().createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    else 
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration,displayMetrics);

}
```

Comment: спасибо вроде немного помогло, но срабатывает через раз и не всегда правильно, например при первом запуске приложения у меня стоит английский, потом я выбираю русский ничего не меняется, потом выбираю англ. и получается русский, укр. вообще не работает, смотрел по ошибкам вроде ничего нету все вроде нормально, за исключением работы эмулятора. Может я еще что-то не учел?