# Локализация через Настройки приложения

Tags: android, локализация, locale, settings

Посмотрел не одно видео о локализации последнее [это](https://youtu.be/fX0YroICMgI) но ни в одном видео или статье нет как сделано в большой части приложений. Зашел в настройки сменил язык все язык везде поменялся.
Нельзя ли как то написать один код для всех TextView которые берут строки в ресурсах.
Например в SettingActivity пишется какой то метод вследствие которого будет использоваться string-ru.xml string-en.xml или строки какого-то другого языка.

Comment: Возможно, имеет смысл не смотреть видео, а читать литературу.

Comment: @Эникейщик  Вы правы, но в литературе которую я читал пишется о локализации просто создать в ресурсах файлы локализации сделать те  самые строки а они уже будут подстраиваться  под язык который установлен на смартфоне. Может вы посоветуете какуй-то книгу или статью? Я не против читать, просто не находил ничего подходящего.

Comment: Тут например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/849559/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-android . Оттуда ссылка есть на это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821538/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android Справа есть еще ссылки на похожие вопросы.

Comment: Хах))) у меня весь этот код написан все это было в этом видео https://youtu.be/ywF-ySiBAsc

Comment: @VladBulan, если у вас код как в приведённых ссылках и вы ищете какое-то другое решение, то оно есть. Но настолько сложное, что совет только один - используете вышепомянутое. Иначе вам надо будет писать свою версию ресурсов и прочее.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое но как говорится когда предоставляют 2 способа, никогда нельзя отрицать 3. Вот нашел сайт какого-то турецкого блогера http://brsatalay.blogspot.com/2017/03/android-localization-activity.html тут очень хорошо все написано даже с кодом на GitHub. Не всегда можно найти сразу то что ищешь.