# Помогите решить проблему с изменением локали на нескольких activity

Tags: android

У меня в приложении я хочу внедрить поддержку нескольких языков, а для этого я создал тестовое приложение направленное только на то что-бы менять языки на нескольких активити. Для своей работы я использовал свой вопрос [Принцип локализации на Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/821538/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-android). Для того что-бы поменять язык на нескольких активити я сохранял значение выбранного языка при помощи sharedPreferences и дальше подгружал это значение при загрузке активити в методе OnCreate. Я специально создал несколько активити и с одинаковым наполнением что-бы увидеть работу программы. Вот код который у меня есть на данный момент:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button first_screen, second_screen, third_screen, english, ukraine, russian;

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    final String LANGUAGE = "lang";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        first_screen = findViewById(R.id.move1);
        second_screen = findViewById(R.id.move2);
        third_screen = findViewById(R.id.move3);

        first_screen.setOnClickListener(this);
        second_screen.setOnClickListener(this);
        third_screen.setOnClickListener(this);

        english = findViewById(R.id.eng);
        ukraine = findViewById(R.id.ua);
        russian = findViewById(R.id.ru);

        english.setOnClickListener(this);
        ukraine.setOnClickListener(this);
        russian.setOnClickListener(this);

        String language = sharedPreferences.getString(LANGUAGE,"");
        LocaleHelper.setLocale(Main2Activity.this, language);
        recreate();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.move1:
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
            case R.id.move2:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.move3:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                break;
            case R.id.eng:
                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("lang", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(LANGUAGE, "eng");
                editor.apply();

            case R.id.ru:
                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("lang", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor1.putString(LANGUAGE, "ru");
                editor1.apply();

            case R.id.ua:
                sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("lang", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor2.putString(LANGUAGE, "ua");
                editor2.apply();


        }
    }
}
```

я думал что язык нужно грузить при создании активити в методе OnCreate. но почему-то приложение слетает и в ошибке указывает на функцию SharedPreferences, которая должна вытащить значение языка. Вот сама ошибка:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.andrew_goroshko.test_localization/com.andrew_goroshko.test_localization.Main2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.andrew_goroshko.test_localization.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Я допускаю что я сделал что-то не так потому-что я только начал работать с SharedPreferences и всех нюансов могу не знать. Заранее спасибо за помощь и советы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> и дальше подгружал это значение при загрузке активити в методе OnCreate.

Именно это в коде отсутствует. Текст ошибки говорит, что идет обращение к несуществующему объекту. Переменная `sharedPreferences` объявляется и потом к ней идет обращение, хотя никакого значения не присвоено. Сначала присвойте переменной значение с помощью `getSharedPreferences()`, а потом уже ее можно использовать.

Примерно так:

```
final String LANGUAGE = "lang";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(LANGUAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

---

Домашнее чтение: [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Comment: да я уже заметил что очень протупил)) вроде все прописал и одна строка все дело запорола))

Comment: вот вроде добавил эту строку, но приложение по какой-то причине вообще теперь не грузится)) ну то есть оно инсталируется, но висит в трее на эмуляторе, а в логах вообще что-то странное творится)) может для этого есть какая-то видимая причина?

Comment: А если перенести ``sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(LANGUAGE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`` внутрь ``onCreate()``?

Comment: так оно и так в onCreate(), я его никуда не вставлял в другое место, ведь при создании активити должен быть загружен последний выбранный язык

Comment: В приведенном коде обе строчки стоят до onCreate().

Comment: может вы имеете в виду само объявление переменных?

Comment: Да вроде правильно все выглядит. Надо тогда логи смотреть.

Comment: сейчас дополню ответ, но там они какие-то зацикленные и бесконечные, так-что я думаю что скину кусок